# Android Have a Table and buttons on the same layout xml

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I've got a page where I want to put a table in the middle and have buttons above and below. I've got the following XML for my layout. But even I can work out it won't work!

Edit: I've updated my XML to show what I want to achive. The tables inside, however it wont let me access by `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation);`

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Add Item" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/lvLocation"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_above="@+id/btnBack"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My code: (with the Db call and array setup taken out)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_list_view);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, mArrayList);

    int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; 
    listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
    listView.setDividerHeight(1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    }



}
```

Heres what i'm trying to achieve. Not the colours, just the concept:

[image]

Comment: The tables inside, however it wont let me access by ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation) What do you mean by tables inside ?

Comment: Sorry, (i'm rubbish at this arent i!) The Listview is appearing in the correct place. http://www.screenup.info/uploads/5440593.jpeg However, I can't seem to get access to the listview to set the items inside

Comment: ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation);
Did you use this to get the reference. What is the error u are getting ?

Comment: lvLocation cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Try cleaning your project and check it.

Comment: That did it. Cheers mate for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Add Item" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd" >

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Should TableLayout actually be ListView (as I want to use it as a list view). I've done that on mine, but it won't let me access it as  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation);

Comment: What is your requirement exactly ?

Comment: I want a listview between two buttons on the top and the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvlocation);
```

Just use:

```
 ListView listView  = getListView();
```

Comment: The method getListView() is undefined for the type LocationListView

Comment: rename your listview as @+id/android:list on your xml layout. if there's still an error, please post the whole Log.